# gcc error while building docker image for django on windows

Tags: django, windows, docker, visual-studio-code, pyodbc

I am trying to build a docker image using Visual Studio Code following this tutorial "https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-deploy-containers".

I created a django app with a connection to a MSSQLserver on azure with the package pyodbc.

During the build of the docker image i receive the following error messages:

```
unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory   
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------   
 Failed building wheel for pyodbc
```

and

```
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for typed-ast
```

I read solutions for linux systems where one should install python-dev, but since i am working on a windows machine this is no solution.

Then i read that on windows all the needed files are in the 'include' directory of the python installation. But in a venv installation this directory is empty... so i created a directory junction to the original 'include'. The error still exists.

My docker file is included below.

```
# Python support can be specified down to the minor or micro version
# (e.g. 3.6 or 3.6.3).
# OS Support also exists for jessie & stretch (slim and full).
# See https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/ for all supported Python
# tags from Docker Hub.
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.6-alpine3.7

# Indicate where uwsgi.ini lives
ENV UWSGI_INI uwsgi.ini

# Tell nginx where static files live (as typically collected using Django's
# collectstatic command.
ENV STATIC_URL /app/static_collected

# Copy the app files to a folder and run it from there
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Make app folder writable for the sake of db.sqlite3, and make that file also writable.
# RUN chmod g+w /app
# RUN chmod g+w /app/db.sqlite3

# If you prefer miniconda:
#FROM continuumio/miniconda3

LABEL Name=hello_django Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 8000

# Using pip:
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "-m", "hello_django"]

# Using pipenv:
#RUN python3 -m pip install pipenv
#RUN pipenv install --ignore-pipfile
#CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python3", "-m", "hello_django"]

# Using miniconda (make sure to replace 'myenv' w/ your environment name):
#RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
#CMD /bin/bash -c "source activate myenv && python3 -m hello_django"
```

I could use some help in building the image without the errors.

---

Based on the answer of 2ps i added these lines almost at the top of the docker file

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.6-alpine3.7

RUN apk update \
  && apk add apk add gcc libc-dev g++ \
  && apk add libffi-dev libxml2 libffi-dev \
  && apk add unixodbc-dev mariadb-dev python3-dev
```

and received a new error...

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.7.1-98-g2f2e944c59 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main]
v3.7.1-105-g7db92f4321 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community]
OK: 9053 distinct packages available
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  add (missing):
    required by: world[add]
  apk (missing):
    required by: world[apk]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk update   && apk add apk add gcc libc-dev g++   && apk add libffi-dev libxml2 libffi-dev   && apk add unixodbc-dev mariadb-dev python3-dev' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

---

Found out that adding

```
RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules
```

helped with the errors above. Taken from: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/55

---

The app now works, exept that the intended connection to the MsSQL database still not works.

```
Error at /

('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I think i should get my hands dirty on some docker documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I gave up on the solution with alpine and switched to debian

```
FROM python:3.7

# needed files for pyodbc
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 libffi-dev unixodbc-dev -y

# MS SQL driver 17 for debian
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -\
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 -y
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was away for a while. Yes, it did work well and probably still does, but i switched jobs and no longer working with Django.

Comment: Well it definitely works, I have this in my base docker image for any project where I need to connect to an MSSQL DB from python. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `apk` to install `gcc` and other native dependencies needed to build your `pip` dependencies.  For the ones that you listed (typedast and pyodbc), I think they would be:

```
RUN apk update \
  && apk add apk add gcc libc-dev g++ \
  && apk add libffi-dev libxml2 libffi-dev \
  && apk add unixodbc-dev mariadb-dev python3-dev
```

Comment: thanks, although it wasnt the complete solution it did help

Comment: Hi, I'm also creating docker on windows trying to use python:3.7.4-slim to import fastparquet.  I'm trying to execute the suggested solutions here and I get :  bin/sh 1:apk: not found.  Any ideas?

Comment: @NivCohen: slim is based on debian.  You would use the following:  `apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install libmariadb-dev unixodbc-dev libffi-dev gcc libc-dev g++ libc-dev libxml2`  I'm double checking package names for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to leave this here for anyone in the future. I'm trying to launch a Python-Flask app with a Spacy model in it into a Docker container and was having trouble installing the packages using pip. Turns out, from this post gcc wasn't installed properly so some basic dependencies were failing.

```
FROM python:3.7

# needed files for pyodbc
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 libffi-dev unixodbc-dev -y
```

Solved my issue of:

```
    Building wheel for cffi (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#8 20.92     Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-i
nstall-ei6nm1zm/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close(
);exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-n8hlmng9 --python-tag cp37:
#8 20.92     unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
#8 20.92     unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
```

and a few other packages that were failing.
Thanks!